# Js change object inside array in for each loop

Tags: javascript

I want to change the current object in for each loop and it does not work, Why it is not working and how can i do this?

```
var arr = [{num: 1}, {num: 2}];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item = {somethingElse: 1}
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I believe you mean map? `arr.map(function(item){return {somethingElse:1}});`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not working because all you're doing is updating the value of the argument you were given (`item`), which doesn't have a live connection to the array. That change disappears as soon as your callback returns.

The most appropriate way to do this is to use `map`:

```
var arr = [{num: 1}, {num: 2}];

arr = arr.map(function(item) {
  return {somethingElse: 1};
});

console.log(arr);
```

`map` gives your function each item and builds a *new* array from whatever you return.

If it's important that you update the array in-place instead of building a new one, you *can* use `forEach`, you just have to assign back to the array element you're updating. The second argument to `forEach`'s callback is the index you're visiting, so:

```
var arr = [{num: 1}, {num: 2}];

arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  arr[index] = {somethingElse: 1};
});

console.log(arr);
```

---

Of course, in both cases above, you'd actually be using `item` for something, which you aren't in your example code... If you wanted to add/remove properties on `item`, not replace the object entirely, [Cyril's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479954/157247) shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Another variety to the list of answers

```
var arr = [{num: 1}, {num: 2}];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.something = 2;//setting the value
  delete item.num;//deleting the num from the object
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the local reference `item` in the callback function.

To change array contents, you need to use the array index and assign new reference to it, as shown in below

```
arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
  arr[i] = {somethingElse: 1} //using index, change the reference in array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not working on the object so changes are not transferred.

You can do this instead:

```
arr.forEach(function(item, ind, array) {
  array[ind] = {somethingElse: 1}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a related note, if you're looking for how to change *a property* of the objects in the array, keep in mind you can just operate on each on your `forEach` loop and the changes will stick:

```
let myArray = [{}];
myArray.forEach((obj) => {obj.foo = "bar";});
console.log(myArray[0].foo); //"bar"
```