# Update Javascript object property inside for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a JS object with another object which seems trivial, but the value is not updating.

```js
let sampleObj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Kelly'
}

let userData = [{
    students: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Sandra'
    }]
  },
  {
    students: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Jerome'
    }]
  }
]

for (let group of userData) {
  for (let student of group.students) {
    if (student.id === sampleObj.id) {
      console.log('updating student object')
      student = sampleObj

      // student = { ...sampleObj }     (another failed attempt)
      // userData[group].students[student] = sampleObj     (another failed attempt)
    }
  }
}

console.log('userData', userData)
```

It seems like, `student` is just some floating thing, unassociated to `userData` at the point where I'm trying to update its value. However, I can't figure out how to make the update or what I'm missing.

**EDIT:** The expected output is to replace the `student` object with `sampleObj` once its found.

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? Do you want to change the found student's name to the new one of the `sampleObj`?

Comment: I would like to replace the entire `student` object with `sampleObj` once its found

Comment: the var `student` only lives inside the inner for loop, so UserData is not affected from the assignment.

Comment: You need to replace the object at the same index in `group.students`.

Comment: `userData[group].students[student]` the `student` (in the last square bracket) doesn't reference anything; you'd need to use an index: `userData[group].students[0]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Js change object inside array in for each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479866/js-change-object-inside-array-in-for-each-loop)

Comment: @DavidThomas there can be multiple `student` objects inside the `students` array. This for loop doesn't have an [index] iterator. What if I don't know the index? It won't always be `0`. Are you suggesting I should be using the other `for loop` instead of a `for ...of loop` ?

Comment: I'd suggest - as connexo does, [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246292/82548). - that you should use an `Array.prototype.forEach()` that way you have access to the array-element, the index and the array itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `forEach(el, index)` instead so you have the index available to do the update:

```js
let sampleObj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Kelly'
}

let userData = [{
    students: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Sandra'
    }]
  },
  {
    students: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Jerome'
    }]
  }
]

userData.forEach((group, m) => {
  group.students.forEach((student, n) => {
    if (student.id === sampleObj.id) {
      console.log('updating student object')
      userData[m].students[n] = sampleObj
    }
  })
})

console.log('userData', userData)
```

Comment: Alright so I was just using the wrong type of for loop. Thanks @connexo !

Answer (score 6):

Array item replacement does not work that way. Instead you can replace the properties of student object like this

```
for (let group of userData) {
  for (let student of group.students) {
    if (student.id === sampleObj.id) {
      console.log('updating student object')
      student = Object.assign(student, sampleObj);
    }
  }
}
```

It'll assign all the properties of samplObj to student object.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Just had to switch the order of parameters passed to `Object.assign(student, sampleObj)`  - student first, sampleObj second . Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You're never updating the actual `userData`. To update it you should reference the `userData` object in the loop, Not the temporary variable which is used to iterate the object.

So try something like:

```
let sampleObj = { id: 1, name: 'Kelly' }

let userData = [
    {
    students: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Sandra' }
    ]
  },
  {
    students: [
        { id: 2, name: 'Jerome' }
    ]
  }
]
let j=0
for ( let group of userData ) {let i=0
    for ( let student of group.students ) { 
    if ( student.id === sampleObj.id ) {
        console.log('updating student object')
        userData[j].students[i] = sampleObj

      // student = { ...sampleObj }     (another failed attempt)
      // userData[group].students[student] = sampleObj     (another failed attempt)
    } i++;
  } j++;
}

console.log('userData', userData)
```