# commit Vuex mutation synchronously after data manipulation inside store action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my Vuex store i have a action which once get result, loop over each element of the result and add's new property to each one.

```
Vue.axios
  .get(endpoint, headers)
  .then(res => {
    if (Array.isArray(res.data) && res.data.length) {
      res.data.forEach(el => {
          el.link = 'some_dynamic_link'
      })
      commit('SET_ACTIVITY', res.data)
    }
  })
```

the problem is that my store ends up with the data from rsult, WITHOUT the `link` added to any of the elements. 
i thought that    something like this tweak will help:
`if (_.has(res.data[res.data.length - 1], 'link')) { commit('SET_ACTIVITY', res.data) }`

but then the mutation just ends up not executing at all, any idea how can i achieve this synchronous behavior ?

**update**
tried to use map instead:

```
.then(res => {
  if (Array.isArray(res.data) && res.data.length) {
    commit('SET_ACTIVITY', res.data.map(el => {
        el.link = 'some_dynamic_link'
    }))
  }
})
```

but than the store contains activities array where elements are `undefined`'s

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479921/3226121)

Comment: assigning  `map`  to a variable and passing it to  the `commit` ends up with the store holding array of `undefined`

Comment: Can you add map example to the question?

Comment: updated my question with the example

Comment: You are missing `return el` in your `map`. Each iteration of `map` MUST `return` something that will go into final array

Comment: yep, you are right, thanks

Comment: I'm glad it worked :)