# Replacing value in an Array in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, foreach

I have an Array localData defined as:

```
public localData: Array<any> = [];
```

In the sample below it has length of 2 and following values in developer tools.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
Country: "United States"
DataSource: ""
FunctionName: "Customer Service"
GroupName: "Main"
Index: 0
Result: undefined
StartDate: "5/1/2012"
StopDate: "
"
1:
Country: "United States"
DataSource: ""
FunctionName: "Customer Service"
GroupName: "Main"
Index: 1
Result: undefined
StartDate: ""
StopDate: "5/1/2019
"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I need to replace the DataSource value to, if blank or if it has any other value then, to a certain value.
I tried doing:

```
 this.localData.forEach(x => x.DataSource ? '' || 'XXX' : 'MyVAL');
```

This code doesn't throw any error but DataSource still remains blank. 
Has anyone had this issue before, or knows why this is happening?

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(localData))`  to show your array. Also you're not setting anything in your `forEach`, so nothing changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Js change object inside array in for each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479866/js-change-object-inside-array-in-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're  not using assignment.
As [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) explains, forEach run the provided function for each element, and your function simply return a boolean if x.DataSource exist, a string otherwise.

If your goal is to change your array you can either modify your function with an assignment:

```
this.localData.forEach(x =>  {
   x.DataSource = x.DataSource ? '' || 'XXX' : 'MyVAL'
});
```

or simply use the map function

```
this.localData = this.localData.map( item => {
   item.DataSource = item.DataSource ? '' || 'XXX' : 'MyVAL'
   return item;
});
```

Clarification:
in your code line

> this.localData.forEach(x => x.DataSource ? '' || 'XXX' : 'MyVAL');

the ternary operator is gonna return 'MyVAL' if x.DataSource is undefined or the empty string, and always 'XXX' if all the other cases.
If i get it right, you want to do something like:

> x.DataSource && x.DataSource !== 'XXX' ? 'MyVAL' : x.DataSource;

which can be read as: if DataSource is evaluated and it's different from 'XXX' assign 'MyVal', keep it as it is otherwise.

EDIT: clarification

Answer (score 4):

try following way:

```
this.localData.forEach(x => (!x.DataSource || x.DataSource === 'XXX') ? 'MyVAL' : x.DataSource);
```

Where

`!x.DataSource` means `x.DataSource === ''`

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function like this:

```
var origin = [{Country: "United States",
DataSource: "",
FunctionName: "Customer Service"},
{
Country: "United States",
DataSource: "US",
FunctionName: "Customer Service"
}
]

origin = origin.map(function(item){ if(item.DataSource == '') 
{
    item.DataSource = 'XXX'
} 
else{ 
item.DataSource = 'MyVAL';
} 
return item;})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array to find the items with the `DataSource` values to replace, and call `forEach` on the filtered items to replace the value:

```
this.localData
  .filter(x => ["", "XXX"].indexOf(x.DataSource) >= 0)
  .forEach(x => x.DataSource = "MyVAL");
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbyx6u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: The filter method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test, so the 
 foeEach would edit this new array. Without reassignment it wouldn't change the original array, would it?

Comment: @Koop4 - If you try the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbyx6u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), you can see that it works. It is because the filtered array contains the items of the original array, and these original items are then modified in `forEach`.

Comment: Yeah, just realized the array is an array of object, and since those are references the new array is different but the items it refers to are the same. Totally logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try for..of (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
for (let item of this.localData) {
 item.DataSource = item.DataSource ? 'XXX' : 'MyVal';
}
```